# How can I create and modify data through inputs using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm starting to learn JavaScript and I got stuck with this piece of code. I'm trying to understand how can users create and modify information using JSON; right now I can enter data but I don't know how the code should look like to modify it using the same inputs. Can someone please assist? This is the code I have at the moment:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body onload="myLoad()">
    <form>
        <label for="track">Track: </label>
        <input type="text" name="track" id="track" required><br>
        <label for="artist">Artist: </label>
        <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" required><br>
        <label for="album">Album: </label>
        <input type="text" name="album" id="album"><br>
        <label for="genre">Genre: </label>
        <select id="genre">
            <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="rock">Rock</option>
            <option value="pop">Pop</option>
            <option value="jazz">Jazz</option>
            <option value="classic">Classic</option>
        </select><br>
        <button onclick="addTrack()">Register a new track</button>
    </form>
    <select id="trackList" onchange="ChangeActiveUser(this.value)">
        <option value="">--Please choose a track--</option>
    </select>

    <script>
var track = [];

function myLoad() {
    let htmlSelect = document.getElementById("trackList");
    htmlSelect.style.visibility = "hidden";

    if (sessionStorage.getItem("hasCodeRunBefore") === null) {
       // let arrayOfPersonObjects = [];
        sessionStorage.setItem("tracks", JSON.stringify(track));
        sessionStorage.setItem("hasCodeRunBefore", true);
    } else {
        track = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tracks"));
        let i = 0;
        track.forEach(function(t) {
            let optItem = document.createElement("option");
            optItem.innerHTML = t.track;
            optItem.value = i;
            i = i + 1;
            htmlSelect.appendChild(optItem);
        });
        if (i > 0) {
            htmlSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
        }
    }
}

function Track(track, artist, album, genre) {
    this.track = track;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.album = album;
    this.genre = genre;
}

function addTrack() {
    track = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("tracks"));
    let newTrack = new Track(
        document.getElementById("track").value,
        document.getElementById("artist").value,
        document.getElementById("album").value,
        document.getElementById("genre").value,
    );
    track.push(newTrack);
    sessionStorage.setItem("tracks", JSON.stringify(track));
}

function ChangeActiveUser(indexOfTrackObj) {
    track[indexOfTrackObj].bio = function() {
        alert(
            this.track +
                " is a " +
                this.genre +
                " song by " +
                this.artist +
                " released on the album " +
                this.album +
                "."
        );
    };
    track[indexOfTrackObj].bio();
}

</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the input values into something like local storage, you can use 
you can find more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```js
//Get the value of input
let artistsInput = document.getElementById("artist").value;

//Convert the artist variable into a string
let artistsStr = JSON.stringify(artists)

//Store the value of artistsStr into localStorage
localStorage.setItem("anything", artistsStr)

//Get the value of localStorage in object form
let artists = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("anything"))
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON, like YAML and XML, is an *encoding scheme.*  You use it to encode and decode data structures as a string.  You treat the string itself as a "black box," relying on the language to encode and decode it.  You know that every language has a compatible implementation of the encoding/decoding process that all of them will understand.  Do not attempt to work with the encoded string "as" a string ...

You commonly find this used in two ways:  (1) with `LocalStorage`, and (2) with "AJAX" calls to a host system.

---

If we're talking about "creating and modifying data," say in a database that is located on the host side, then we are necessarily talking about AJAX.  I'd like to please refer you to any of thousands of tutorials about that subject, such as this one by the ever-excellent w3schools:  https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp.

I'm certain that you will very quickly understand how it works, and how JSON, YAML, *etc.* figure into it.